# Difference between wp_salt schemes

Tags: plugin-development

I am running a wordpress user system with 15k users/day. I have a custom message system and there is an issue in it. Sometimes (like at 1/1000 users) [`wp_hash`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash) that generates security nonce returns different value that the one that checks it. The algorithms are the same.

Could the issue be that I am using the default "auth" scheme, or should I use the "nonce" scheme instead?

I am using W3 Total Cache, could it influence it?